# Continuous streaming connections are unstable on a Windows 8 tablet

Tags: windows-8, wireless-networking, streaming, wifi-configuration

I'm trying to listen to a radioshow live on a tablet and on a laptop (audio streaming, **no** video decoding), both are connected to the same Wi-Fi network. It looks like the wi-fi connection on my tablet is unstable. The laptop works fine.

**TL;DR:** The stream plays for like 1-5 minutes and then stops and tries to reconnect. Sometimes when I'm trying to connect it just shows me a timeout error. Tried using different players, as well as listening in a browser.

Here's how I've narrowed the issue down: the laptop works perfectly fine and is able to play the stream for up to 10 hours without any interruption - this means the issue is not with the stream, the wi-fi connection or the player.

I've also noticed that sometimes the connection lags while I'm using other software like web-browser or FTP client.

So how do I find out what's wrong with that tablet? It runs Windows 8 which means it should be able to handle the streaming content just fine. I remember there were some limitations on simultaneous connections in Windows XP, but I believe those were removed when the Service Pack 3 was released back in 2008. Windows 8 is supposed to be a modern OS with stable connectivity.

Tried disabling the Antivirus and Firewall software so that's out of the equation too.

Updated the Wi-Fi driver as well.

Again, the internet works. I am able to browse websites and listen to that radio for a while. On rare occasions it plays for several hours, which means the issue is random. I've tried to make sure there are no background downloads running and checked the task manager to confirm the tablet is not overloaded with some background tasks.

Does Windows 8 provide a way to see why is the connection interrupted? The issue is annoying and I'll appreciate any help in fixing it.

**UPDATE1**: The tablet is an HP Elitepad 900 running Windows 8. The driver is *Atheros AR600x 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Driver* updated from the version *3.7.0.185 (12/27/2012)* to *3.7.1.8 (10/14/2013)*. The router is an *Asus RT-N10U* (but again, the same Wi-Fi works fine on the laptop I'm using). The laptop that works uses the *Atheros AR5005G Wireless Network Adapter v. 5.3.0.45 (02/05/2007)*

**UPDATE2** @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thanks for the advice, tried playing and doing `ping -t` simultaneously. I can see the `Request timed out.` message precisely when playback pauses. At the same time, the same stream on a laptop connected to the same Wi-Fi network keeps playing. Here's [a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ehkyd.png).

**UPDATE3** When I was trying to save that screenshot over LAN it showed me a message saying "*Paint cannot save the file because the connection was interrupted*", and it worked fine when I've tried again. I did also notice that the list of the available networks in the Wi-Fi area on the right updates constantly, but the main network I'm connected to does always show "Connected"

Comment: Information about the access point is required to explain this behavior.  Information about the network device on both the laptop and the tablet is required to explain this behavior.

Comment: @Ramhound please see updated

Comment: I asked for information on both the laptop and the tablet.  I cannot explain the behavior without the information on the laptop.

Comment: That tablet has a 1.5GHz Atom processor in it -- not exactly a video-decoding powerhouse. Start a `ping -t` against a well-kow internet site. Then start streaming. If the stream pauses, but the pings keep going, then your network isn't dropping.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 It shouldn't be disconnecting from the network.  If my 3rd generation Kindle Fire can process HD video I am certain the Atom can also.  It might have trouble, there might be artifacts, but the connectivity seems to be the problem.

Comment: @Ramhound I see, just updated the question, the adapter information is there, sorry about the misunderstanding and thank you for your help

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 thanks for the advice, tried playing and doing `ping -t` simultaneously, I can see the `Request timed out.` message precisely when playback pauses. At the same time, the same stream on a laptop connected to the same Wi-Fi network keeps playing.

Comment: found something http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/241501-wireless-internet-sometimes-dropping-out.html and http://forums.laptopvideo2go.com/topic/15297-latest-atheros-modded-driver-for-windows-7-vista-and-winxp/page-28, will take a closer look later